# Create a Column to Group Rows and Count Sequentially

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a `Column 1` which in this case is the same value repeating through all the rows. `Column 2` has non distinct rows in which values may repeat. I want to create a column named `Group` to show that the rows belong to this group in seqential order (Ordered by `Column 2`). Basically, I need to create an output that looks similar to this:

```
Column 1   | Column 2   | Group
--------------------------------
100        | AA         | 1
100        | AA         | 1
100        | AA         | 1 
100        | BB         | 2
100        | BB         | 2
100        | CC         | 3
100        | DD         | 4
100        | DD         | 4
```

Comment: What is the point of having duplicate rows?

Comment: The query only pulls a few column off of a table. If I selected all columns they would be distinct. It's only duplicated for querying purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the dense_rank function in oracle.

```
select col1,
       col2,
       dense_rank () over (partition by col1
                         order by col2) group_column
  from test_table;

      COL1 CO GROUP_COLUMN
---------- -- ------------
       100 AA            1
       100 AA            1
       100 AA            1
       100 BB            2
       100 BB            2
       100 CC            3
       100 DD            4
       100 DD            4
```

You could use "order by col1, col2" to verify the results.

Answer (score 2):

The function that you want is `dense_rank` not `rank`:

```
select column1, column2,
       dense_rank() over (order by column2)
from t
```

DENSE_RANK() produces numbers from 1 to the number of groups, with no gaps.  Also, this should not have a partition, for what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
with list as
(select distinct col2 from tab order by 1),
      listnum as
(select rownum, col2 from list)

select * 
from listnum l
join tab t on t.col2=l.col2;
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5983b/14/0)

Links about code I used:

- [WITH Clause](http://psoug.org/reference/with.html) - examples
- [ROWNUM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) - documenation